# View is not sending right data to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple partial view and I am using ajaxform. In my partial view I have one sigle textArea and a Submit button.
The problem is whatever I write into the text area, It does not send the data to controller, rather it sends a text which is = "Comment".
If I dont write anything, the validation works perfect.

The Viewmodel:

```
public class NoteCommentViewModel
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Hey, if you dont wanna write then why pressing the button !!")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public Guid NoteId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
//
    //GET:/Notes/Comment/
    public ActionResult Comment(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.NoteId = id;
        var m = new NoteCommentViewModel()
        {
            NoteId = new Guid(id),
            UserId = Convert.ToInt64(Session["LoginUserId"].ToString()),
            //Comment=""

        };
        return PartialView(m);
    }
    //
    //POST:/Notes/Comment
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Comment(NoteCommentViewModel nvm)
    {
        NoteRatingComments comment = new NoteRatingComments();
        comment.Comment = nvm.Comment; // Here I always have "Comment", regardless whatever I write in the page.
        comment.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
        comment.NoteId = nvm.NoteId;
        comment.UserId = nvm.UserId;
        comment.Rating = 3.00;

        dc.NoteRatingComments.AddObject(comment);
        dc.SaveChanges();

        return Content(Boolean.TrueString);
    }
```

The view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"    type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Comment", "Notes", null, new AjaxOptions
{
UpdateTargetId = "Comment-message",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
HttpMethod = "POST",
OnSuccess = "commentSuccess"
}, new { id = "commentForm" }))
{
<div style="margin-top:20px;">
<div id="commentSuccess"></div>
<div class="comentPic">
    @{
        long UserId = Convert.ToInt64(Session["LoginUserId"].ToString());
        string Fullname = Session["LoginUserFullName"].ToString();
    }
  <img src='https://graph.facebook.com/@UserId/picture' height="100px" width="100px"/>
</div>
<div class="commentText">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.NoteId)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comment, new { style = "width:600px;height:120px;" })
    <br />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Comment)
    <div style="text-align:right;">
        <input type="submit" value="Comment" name="comment" class="btn"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

</div>
}
```

Here is the screen shot of the error...for better understanding. I am writing "data" in the view but in the controller I am getting "Comment"..Where is it coming from??

[image]

[image]
WOuld be great if someone can help me to identify the problem...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your submit button's `name` attribute is the same as the `Comment` textarea `name` attribute.

To resolve this you need to change the submit button's `name` to something else than "comment" or remove the `name` attribute from your submit button, so change:

```
<input type="submit" value="Comment" name="comment" class="btn"/>
```

To

```
<input type="submit" value="Comment" class="btn"/>
```

Because the `Ajax.BeginForm` uses the the jQuery [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method which - because your submit button has a `name` and this input triggers the submit - also sends the submit button's value `"Comment"` to the server.

Comment: heyy...Thats super cool. solved my problem and i also learned a good thing. Thanks m8.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly your problem is. But the below code should work.

```
public class NoteCommentViewModel
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage=" Your Error message")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]   
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    //other properties
}
```

And in your `View`, Use it like this

```
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Comment)
```

Comment: It didnt work. I have added the screen shot for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

actually your code is very confusing. in your view u didn`t use Model and seems you use m as your model and as i know this is completely wrong.i don`t know your view is rendering but wherever you use m=>m.sth the second m must be nothin.instead  you must define your @model NoteCommentViewModel at first of cshtml file and then use Model instead of second m

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for writing. But actually I have @ViewModels.NoteCommentViewModel added. I just didnt write it here..:)